# Unwanted redirect from a domain to my site

Tags: domains, htaccess, redirects

An external person from my client company registered a domain and redirected to my client URL.

For instance, if you type `unwanteddomain.com` it redirects to `myclientdomain.com`.

Is there any way to block or redirect (for second time) to nowhere the `unwanteddomain.com` via cPanel or any rewrite rules on *.htaccess*?

Comment: Presumably you cannot contact or work with the external person. I would work with your host and request that they configure the web server to only accept requests for myclientdomain.com and www.myclientdomain.com. I did this recently with my host, although that was with IIS.

Comment: The unwanted domain is the name of another company that has good relations with my client but they do not want to be redirected to my clients. Obviously a claim is in the works, meanwhile I must block the redirect.

Comment: Got a solution using RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.unwanteddomain.com$ [NC] I will post bellow once I can (Because I am new to PW I must wait 8 hours to answer my own question)

Comment: If this is a "normal" 301 HTTP redirect, which would seem to be implied, then it's difficult to see how a solution using `HTTP_HOST` would work? If `HTTP_HOST` is working for you then I'd wager they have set up `unwanteddomain.com` in DNS as an `A` record that points to `myclientdomain.com` - but this is not a "redirect".

Comment: I checked the A record, it does not point to my client IP. Using HTTP_REFERER just blocked the full site (maybe I applied the rule the wrong way).

Comment: It's just that if this is a "redirect" (as you state in the question) then `HTTP_HOST` (at `myclientdomain.com`) will _never_ be set to `unwanteddomain.com`?! Which is why I assumed it must be some kind of DNS mapping. (?!)

Answer (score 6):

Finally resolved using these rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.unwanteddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://whateverPlaceYouWantToSend.com [R,L]
```

`HTTP_REFERER` did not work so I used `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: Is the `!`, preceding the `RewriteCond` pattern, intentional? Otherwise this appears to do the complete opposite of what you are trying to achieve in the question and redirects every _other_ domain, _except_ `unwanteddomain.com`!?

Comment: No, corrected! My typo.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this is block all requests which are coming from `unwantedcomain.com` by checking for `HTTP_REFERER`

- Block traffic from a single domain:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} unwateddomain\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule .* - [F]
  ```
- Block traffic from multiple domains:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} unwanteddomain\.com [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} anotherdomain\.com
  RewriteRule .* - [F]
  ```

Comment: If this is a "redirect" (as in a 301 HTTP redirect) then the `HTTP_REFERER` won't be set to `unwanteddomain.com`. The `HTTP_REFERER` will only be set in this case if the user was following a _link_ from `unwanteddomain.com`.